# Picking out from a string

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

How do I write a program in a way where if a user inputs a website name, how would the program determine if its a com, gov, org, edu entity? Its a problem on a chapter I've read. This chapter brings up If/else statements, and switch statements. so I'm sure it has to revolve around those. but every one of there examples utilizes ints. I think I would be utilizing strings for this problem, but the book hasn't really helped me on that front.

this is my code/pseudocode for now...

```
package ch5_inClass;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindingWebAddressEntity
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //enter web site
        String webAddress;

        System.out.println("Please enter web site name: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        webAddress = scan.next();

        //determine last three characters of the web address
        if(webAddress)
        {
            System.out.println("this is a gov website");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("this is not a gov website");
        }
        //display government entity if gov
        //display university entity if edu
        //display commercial entity if com
        //display organization entity if org


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) function. Something like:

```
if(webAddress.endsWith(".gov") {
   System.out.println("This is a gov address");
}
else if(webAddress.endsWith(".edu") {
   System.out.println("This is an edu address");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`endsWith()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method from `String` . Utilize it with `if` and `else` statement like this

```
String s = "oliver.com";
if(s.endsWith(".com")){
    System.out.println("its a dot come site");
} else if (s.endsWith(".gov")) {
    System.out.println("its a government site");
}
```

then this will print out `its a dot come site`

hope this helps